# Why boost filesystem and libpq-fe headers won't compile in the same file

Tags: c++, boost

Am having a challenge in linking my file when boost/filesystem.hpp and libpq-fe.h headers are in the same file, see code below:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

My compiling command:

```
/d/MinGW/bin/g++ -o filesys filesys.cpp -Ilib/sqlite3/ -I"/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include/" -I/c/local/boost_1_71_0/
```

Please note, if I comment out `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` and `using namespace boost::filesystem;` then compile using the same command line parameters, the file compiles with no errors!

This are the errors am getting:

```
-I"/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include/" -I/c/local/boost_1_71_0/
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6BrwZR.o:filesys.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_init'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6BrwZR.o:filesys.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_destroy'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6BrwZR.o:filesys.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_lock'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6BrwZR.o:filesys.cpp:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `__imp_pthread_mutex_unlock'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My environment:

- Windows 7
- MinGW/gcc version 8.2.0
- Boost version 1_71

Regards,
PG

Comment: Possible workaround: use [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Comment: "Am having a challenge" is a very bad description. Please, provide the exact compiler/linker error.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, unfortunately, am using boost because  std::filesystem won't compile with my version of MinGW

Comment: @lisyarus, ops sorry, I forgot to show the errors, I have edited the question, now showing the errors.

Comment: `using namespace whatever` is NOT your friend. Never do that.

Comment: @n.m, sure,  but still it doesn't solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

append `-pthread` option when compile.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem!
Am using MinGW distribution from Stephan T. Lavavej website [nuwen](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) which has boost 1.69 library included. Then I have my own boost installation version 1.71 that I was trying to link with, guess that was causing a conflict. [1](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

This is how am compiling the application:

```
 /d/MinGW/bin/g++ -o filesys filesys.cpp -Ilib/sqlite3/ -I"/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/include/" -I/d/MinGW/include/ -lpthread -std=c++17
```

Now it compiles fine.